# mapView:viewForAnnotation: not called when delegate set in code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a custom class for my MKAnnotations, I want to override the default `mapView:viewForAnnotatation` method so that I can add extra information in the callout. When I set my delegate in code (as per the code below) the annotations are dropped on the map and are selectable but my `mapView:viewForAnnoation` is never called.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation: called");
    MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
    if(!aView){
        aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
    }
    aView.annotation = annotation;

    return aView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

}
```

I know the delegate is being set as I can override the method `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` and I see an NSLog when I select an annotation.

When I change from setting the delegate in code to setting it in the Storyboard the method is called (NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation: called"); statements appear) but the annotations don't appear on the map and sometimes this error appears:

```
<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData *** CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData: bad readSession [0x8618480]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like two separate issues:

1. Regarding the setting delegate in code v storyboard, it's hard to reconcile your various observations (delegate method `didSelectAnnotationView` is getting called in both scenarios, but `viewForAnnotation` is not). The only difference between setting it in code v in the storyboard is the timing of when the `delegate` is getting set. You're not showing us the process of adding the annotations, so it's hard to diagnose on the basis of what you've described. If none of your delegate methods were getting called, I'd suspect the `mapView` `IBOutlet`, but if some are working and others aren't, I can only suspect a timing issue.
2. Regarding the setting of the `MKAnnotationView`, the default implementation does nothing. You either need to write your own subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, set its image if you're using your own image, or, much easier, just use `MKPinAnnotationView`. But just creating a `MKAnnotationView` won't do anything. You really want:

   ```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
       // If it's the user location, just return nil.
       if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
           return nil;

       // Handle any custom annotations.
       MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
       if(aView){
           aView.annotation = annotation;
       } else {
           aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
       }

       aView.canShowCallout = NO;

       return aView;
   }
   ```

   (Note, I'm not only creating a `MKPinAnnotationView`, but I'm also making sure that it's not a `MKUserLocation`, in case you ever choose to show user location on the map. I'm also going to explicitly set the `canShowCallout`, as that's presumably the reason you're writing this method at all.)

Bottom line, if you want to show a simple pin annotation view, use `MKPinAnnotationView`. Using `MKAnnotationView` alone will result in no annotations from appearing.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is searching for a reason why `mapView:viewForAnnotatation` is not being called when the delegate is set in code, there is a bug in iOS 6 - http://openradar.appspot.com/12346693

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I wanted to share my solution:

I also override

`(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation`

But I realised that these Annotations work similar to TableView and iOS will reuse the annotations like the cells in TVC (table view controller)

Since I was only using one Identifier `mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"mapPin"` it would not need to call ViewForAnnotation again if it had enough 'annotation' in memory.

So my solution was to create multiple Identifier the first time the map load based on my conditions.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i just dropped to this question accidentally when i was searching for the same problem.

I solved my problem, in my case im resizing the `mapview`. 
I added `delegate` after i resize the `mapview`. it works now perfectly.!